# Avoid an animations to set the display style to "block"?

Tags: jquery, css

MY animation creates a display style 'block' for the duration of the animation, how can I avoid it?

Comment: You should add some code and HTML to help us at helping you.

Comment: You can't avoid it if it's initial style is inline due to the fact that inline elements don't respect width and height.

Comment: Ok, i will ask on a forum nevermind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
$("span").fadeIn("slow");
```